# issue with windows authentication username and password

Tags: windows, authentication, web-config, authorization

I have set my web application to be secured by windows authentication.

I am not sure if I have done so correctly though - when I attempt to access the site I get the pop up looking for a username and password. However no matter what combination of such that I used, it does not work.

Where can I retrieve or at least set up a valid user name and password to use?

Comment: Do you include the domain in the user name, namely _domain\username_?

Comment: How do I know what domain to include? Where can I find this?

Comment: that depends on where the users are defined. If they are defined on a domain, use the domain name. If they are local users, use the machine name. I'm not sure this applies to your case (never done what you're doing), but it makes sense to me. You can also try to access the server as `\\servername\c$`, and see what user gets you through. Again, I don't know for sure it's the same mechanism, but it's worth trying...

Answer (score 0):

When you setup an IIS server to use Windows authentication, the user accounts are usually those managed on the server or Active Directory (if the server is part of a domain).

For more information on how user authentication is handled in IIS, check out [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292114%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).